# sapui5: how to pass the table columns from one view to other

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Hi to all the experts,

I'm a quite new in sapui5 and have a following scenario in the list.view.js I've defined a simple Table:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

sap.ui.jsview("fst.app.cList", {

    getControllerName: function () {
        return "fst.app.cList";
    },

    createContent: function (oController) {

        //Back button
        var oBackButton = new sap.m.Button({
            text: "Back",
            icon: "sap-icon://arrow-left",
            press: oController.handleButtonPress
        });

        //New contract button
        var oNewButton = new sap.m.Button({
            text: "New",
            icon: "sap-icon://add-document",
            press: oController.addNewButtonPress
        });

        //Spacer
        var oSpacer = sap.m.ToolbarSeparator();

        //Table body
        var oTable = sap.m.Table({
            insert: true,
            headerText: "List of Items",
            headerDesign: sap.m.ListHeaderDesign.Standard,
            mode: sap.m.ListMode.None,
            includeItemInSelection: false
        });

        //Columns
        var col01 = new sap.m.Column("col01", {
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Number"
            })
        });
        oTable.addColumn(col01);

        var col02 = new sap.m.Column("col02", {
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Product"
            })
        });
        oTable.addColumn(col02);

        var col03 = new sap.m.Column("col03", {
            header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Date"
            })
        });
        oTable.addColumn(col03);

        var colItems = new sap.m.ColumnListItem("colItems", {
            type: "Active"
        });
        oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/value", colItems);

        var txtNAME = new sap.m.Text("txtNAME", {
            text: "{ProductID}"
        });
        colItems.addCell(txtNAME);

        var txtNAME2 = new sap.m.Text("txtNAME2", {
            text: "{ProductName}"
        });
        colItems.addCell(txtNAME2);

        var txtNAME3 = new sap.m.Text("txtNAME3", {
            text: "{UnitsInStock}"
        });
        colItems.addCell(txtNAME3);

        var page = new sap.m.Page({

            title: "Test",
            enableScrolling: false,
            content: [oBackButton, oSpacer, oNewButton, oTable]

        });

        return page;
    }
    });
})();
```

When the Button (oNewButton) will be clicked the new view will be called (new.view.js). In this view I'd like to have a form with the columns from the first view.

Could anyone give me some tipps how to implement such a scenario in a best way?

Thanks in advance and best regards.
Denis

Answer (score 0):

The best way to navigate from one view to another is to use the Router. Check this quick tutorial to learn how it works.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html

To pass parameters in the navigation I guess you have two options.
1.-  Pass them as parameter in the route pattern. Those will appear in the hash path. Check this for the patterns options:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.PatternMatching/preview

2.- If you have to pass many fields, create a model in the Component scope. The Component scope is accesible from all views. Just use sap.ui.getCore().setModel() and in the target view sap.ui.getCore().getModel()
Then set the Model you have get from the Core to the container where you have your form.
Here a snippet: https://jsbin.com/tekisokevu/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' >
 <meta charset="UTF-8" >
 <title>test</title>

 <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.5/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
  data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
  data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"></script>

 <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <core:ComponentContainer name='my.comp'/>
  </mvc:View>
 </script>

 <script id="home" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   controllerName="my.controller1">
   <Page>
    <Table id="myTable">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Modify the column names and press + ==> " />
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onAddPress"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Input palceholder="Column Name" value="Column1"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Input palceholder="Column Name" value="Column2"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Input palceholder="Column Name" value="Column3"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="Text1" />
                                <Text text="Text2" />
                                <Text text="Text3" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="Text1" />
                                <Text text="Text2" />
                                <Text text="Text3" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="Text1" />
                                <Text text="Text2" />
                                <Text text="Text3" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
   </Page>
  </mvc:View>
 </script>

 <script id="add" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
   controllerName="my.controller2">
   <Page id="page" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onBack">
                <VBox items="{columnsModel>/columns}">
                  <items>
                    <HBox class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin">
                      <Label text="{columnsModel>columnName}:" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd sapUiSmallMarginTop"/>
                      <Input placeholder="{columnsModel>columnName} value"/>
                    </HBox>
                  </items>
                </VBox>
   </Page>
  </mvc:View>
 </script>
  
 <script>
  // jQuery.sap.declare("my.comp.Component");
  sap.ui.define("my/comp/Component", ["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function(UIComponent) {
   return UIComponent.extend("my.comp.Component", {
    metadata : {
     name : "GreatComponent",
     version : "1.0",
     includes : [],
     dependencies : {
      libs : ["sap.m"]
     },
     routing: {
      config: {
       routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
       viewType: "XML",
       viewPath: "my",
       controlId: "app",
       transition: "slide",
       controlAggregation: "pages"
      },
      routes: [
       {
        name: "home",
        pattern: "",
        target: "home"
       },
       {
        name: "add",
        pattern: "add",
        target: "add"
       }
      ],
      targets: {
       home: {
        viewName: "Home",
        title: "home"
       },
       add: {
        viewName: "Add",
        title: "add"
       }
      }
     }
    },
    init: function() {
     sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
     var oRouter = this.getRouter();
     var oViews = oRouter.getViews();
     this.runAsOwner(function() {
      var myHome = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#home').html()});
      oViews.setView("my.Home", myHome);
      var myAdd = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#add').html()});
      oViews.setView("my.Add", myAdd);
     });
     oRouter.initialize();
    },
    createContent : function() {
     var componentData = this.getComponentData();
     return new sap.m.App("app", {
     });
    }
   });
  });
      
  sap.ui.define("my/controller1", [
          "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
        ],function(UIComponent) {
   return sap.ui.controller("my.controller1", {
    onInit: function() {
     this.oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this.getView());

                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                    var oData = {
                       columns: []
                    }
                    oModel.setData(oData);
                    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "columnsModel");
    },
              
    onAddPress: function() {
                    var aColumnsNames = [];
                    var aColumns = this.getView().byId("myTable").getColumns();
                    for (var i=0; i<aColumns.length; i++){
                        var sColumnName = aColumns[i].getHeader().getValue();
                        var oItem = {columnName: sColumnName};
                        aColumnsNames.push(oItem);
                    }
                    sap.ui.getCore().getModel("columnsModel").setProperty("/columns", aColumnsNames);
                  
                  
     this.oRouter.navTo("add");
                }
   });
  });
      
  sap.ui.define("my/controller2", [
          "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
        ],function(UIComponent) {
   return sap.ui.controller("my.controller2", {
    onInit: function() {
     this.oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this.getView());
                  
                    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("columnsModel");
                    this.getView().byId("page").setModel(oModel, "columnsModel");
    },
                onBack: function(){
                    this.oRouter.navTo("home");
                }
   });
  });
  sap.ui.require(["my/comp/Component"], function(myComp) {
   // instantiate the View
   sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}).placeAt('content');
  });
 </script>

</head>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
 <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```